# Same Jupyter config, two different behaviors

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I used a working Jupyter configuration file on another machine, and got the following error. The configuration file parameters are basically those given in the [instructions for setting up a server](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html). Can anyone help diagnose?

```
ubuntu@ip:~$ jupyter lab
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 528, in get
    value = obj._trait_values[self.name]
KeyError: 'allow_remote_access'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 869, in _default_allow_remote
    addr = ipaddress.ip_address(self.ip)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/ipaddress.py", line 54, in ip_address
    address)
ValueError: '' does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-lab", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 266, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1629, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterlab/labapp.py", line 353, in init_webapp
    super().init_webapp(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1379, in init_webapp
    self.jinja_environment_options,
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 158, in __init__
    default_url, settings_overrides, jinja_env_options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 251, in init_settings
    allow_remote_access=jupyter_app.allow_remote_access,
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 556, in __get__
    return self.get(obj, cls)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 535, in get
    value = self._validate(obj, dynamic_default())
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 872, in _default_allow_remote
    for info in socket.getaddrinfo(self.ip, self.port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` for the line `c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'`, and if found change it to e.g. `c.NotebookApp.ip = '0.0.0.0'`. This fixed it for me.

Source: https://forums.fast.ai/t/jupyter-notebook-keyerror-allow-remote-access/24392